# How do I code in PHP this instruction provided by a vendor "DELETE /<domain>/unsubscribes/<address>"

Tags: php

I am working with Mailgiun.  Their documentation shows a php example for obtaining a list of email addresses (see below), which I have working in my own code.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient  = Mailgun::create('PRIVATE_API_KEY', 'https://API_HOSTNAME');
$domain    = 'YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME';
$recipient = 'bob@example.com';
$tag       = '*';

# Issue the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->suppressions()->unsubscribes()->create($domain, $recipient, $tag);
```

I want to remove an entry in their list, and their code example for doing so only shows the following line of code:

```
DELETE /<domain>/unsubscribes/<address>
```

How do I code the line above using PHP?

Note:
I have tried the following block of code,

```
$result = $mailgun_client->suppressions()->bounces()->delete('mg.quikkast.com', 'emailaddress@gmail.com');
```

but get back a the following error:

Mailgun\Exception\HttpClientException: The endpoint you have tried to access does not exist. Check if the domain matches the domain you have configure on Mailgun.

Thus far Mailgun has not responded with a solution to my support ticket.  So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That looks correct. Your error message does not seem to reflect your code. Make sure. that's the exact line that the error is referring to.

Comment: Yes that is the error that is occurring within Mailgun's library.  When I debug it, the error occurs in their library and never returns from the php call I made to Mailgun

Comment: It has been two days and I am still waiting for an answer from Mailgun.  Is there some other way to code the Delete request in PHP that I should be using?

Comment: Sorry - I just realized I posted the wrong the error code.  Let me correct it.

Comment: I updated the error code - sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Ah ha, that does sound more like a API or library issue than a coding issue. https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/issues/586 suggests making sure you're using the dev-master branch of the library. You can also test it on the command line by doing `curl -s --user 'api:your-api-key' -X "DELETE" 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.quikkast.com/bounces/emailaddress@gmail.com'` to make sure those settings will work.

Comment: Thanks - I will give that a try.

Comment: I found it interesting that Mailgun's error message incorrectly stated "configure on Mailgun" instead of "configured on Mailgun".

Comment: Looks like that's a [library-set error](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/blob/7b674dd2cac86b120195ef1538ca9933c6b2f1e5/src/Exception/HttpClientException.php)

Comment: I may have to update to the latest version of MG.  I am currently on 2.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to latest version of MG library.  Posted a new question to specifically get MG to correct error their code is reporting.